# How to find a unique solution, infinite solution and no solution for this matrix.

Tags: matrices

The question on my page is

> For what value(s) of k does the system have, no solutions, a unique
>   solution, and infinitely many solutions?
>
> [image]

All help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Press the link on the question to see the matrix.

Comment: Use Rouché-Capelli theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start from the last row.

If $k^2 - 2k = 0$, which means $k^2 = 2k \iff k = 0 \vee k = 2$ then there can be two situations:

1. Infinite many solutions if $5k + 11 = 0$, which means $k=-11/5$, as there is at least one empty row, leading to at least one free variable, or
2. no solution if $5k +11 \ne 0$, which means $k \ne -11/5$.

If $k^2 - 2k \ne 0$ then we can transform the system to
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 2 & 0 & -3 + (5k+11)/(k^2 - 2k) \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -5 + (k+3)(5k+11)/(k^2-2k) \\
0 & 0 & 1 & (5k+11)/(k^2 - 2k)
\end{array}
\right]
\to \\
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 0 & 0 & 7 + (1-2(k+3))(5k+11)/(k^2 - 2k) \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -5 + (k+3)(5k+11)/(k^2-2k) \\
0 & 0 & 1 & (5k+11)/(k^2 - 2k)
\end{array}
\right]
\to \\
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 0 & 0 & 7 + (-2k-5)(5k+11)/(k^2 - 2k) \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -5 + (k+3)(5k+11)/(k^2-2k) \\
0 & 0 & 1 & (5k+11)/(k^2 - 2k)
\end{array}
\right]
$$
which gives a unique solution.

Alas the first case can not happen. For both $k=0$ or $k=2$ there will be no solution, for other values of $k$ there will be a unique solution.

Comment: Sorry mate just to clarify, there is either a unique solution or no solution, but in no instance are there infinite solutions?

Comment: Yes. Infinite many solutions can not happen.

Answer (score 0):

Did you **try** to solve the system of equation?  In order to reduce the first 3 columns to the identity matrix, you will eventually have to divide by some polynomial in k.  For any k such that that polynomial is not 0, there will be a unique solution.  For k such that that polynomial is 0, if the last column (after the row reduction) is also 0 then there are infinitely many solutions. If there is any number in the last column (after the row reduction) that is not 0, there is no solution.